# docker image 7.0.13-fpm Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Tags: php, docker, fpm, debian-jessie

I am trying to build an image:

```
FROM php:7.0.13-fpm

RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev
```

and getting error:

```
#5 3.560 Err http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
#5 3.560   404  Not Found
#5 3.590 Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
#5 3.590   404  Not Found
#5 3.593 W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.132 80]
#5 3.593
#5 3.593 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#5 3.593
#5 3.593 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#5 3.593
#5 3.593 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried different options but still not able to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: The Stack Overflow questions around this tend to point at [Failed to fetch jessie backports repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) on [unix.se], which notes that Debian 8 (Jessie) was end-of-lifed in 2020 and isn't getting updates of any sort any more.  If your language runtime is similarly that old, you should strongly consider updating it to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

the fix was to add

```
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```